# Nabla operation to cos and sin replacement

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, laplace-transform, laplacian

There are given equations,

$$ x = x' \cos \theta - y'\sin \theta   \\
y = x' \sin \theta + y'\cos \theta
 $$

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x'} $$

I don't understand how it is equal to $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \sin \theta $$

Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ and $y$ are functions that depend on $x'$ and $y'$, i.e.,
$$x(x',y') = x' \cos\theta-y' \sin\theta,\\
y(x',y') = x' \sin\theta+y' \cos\theta.
$$

So
\begin{align} \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}(x' \cos\theta-y' \sin\theta) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}(x' \cos\theta)\\
&=\cos \theta.
\end{align}

Similarly, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x'} = \sin \theta.$

This is why it is equal to your last equation.